How to freeze a dynamic object
Here is a example of dynamic object that was dumped and changed . The dump value also includes the changes that were made after the dump. This is almost like looking into the future.
The linqpad code share is at https://share.linqpad.net/m86box7v.linq
void Main()
{
    List<ExpandoObject> lo= new List<ExpandoObject>();
    dynamic eo;
    eo = new ExpandoObject();
    eo.first="originalvaluebeforefirstdump";
    lo.Add(eo);
    lo.Dump("firstdump");
    eo.seond="newvaluesaftefirstdump";
     
    
}



i did not expect to see column 2 in the dump as the values were added after

figured out a answer. i did a deep serialization and deserialized it.

Dumping to DataGrids in LINQPad will exhibit this behavior because data grids show you live information.
If you want to see a snapshot, use the (default) Results to Rich Text option. This serializes the data to HTML whenever you dump.
